# Css Position Property

Tags: css, position

It's the image without using position property
[image]

```
.Brand-image {
   width: 55%;
   transform: rotate (25deg);
   margin-left: 20%;
   position: absolute;
```

But after applying above position property it's size increases
[image]

Comment: You seem to have failed to ask a *question*. We're not sure what your design is *supposed* to look like; you need to specify that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your width is being calculated as a percentage of the parent width.

When you change the position to absolute, the bounding element becomes the page body, so the width is calculated as a percent of the body width.

Using absolute positioning always leads to difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the parent `position: relative;`. Then the image will take 55% width of its relative parent div.